# Magento: addAttributeToFilter but ignore for products that don't have this attribute?

Tags: attributes, magento, filter, exists, not-exists

I'm trying to show add some filters on my store, but they have a nasty side effect.

Suppose I have product type A and B. Now I want to only show A where color = blue/red.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
    ->addCategoryFilter($this)
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
          array('attribute' => 'color', 'in' => array(4, 6)),
    )
    );
```

This does the trick, but now because product type B has no value assigned to color(since this attribute isn't appointed to it) no products for this type show up.

I had found this code on the forum http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/178309, but it doesn't work:

```
array('attribute' => 'color', 'is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null'))
```

Neither does:

```
array('attribute' => 'color', 'null' => true),
```

That actually shows products which have the attribute assigned but with no value declared...

I also tried adding:

```
array('attribute' => 'price', 'gteq' => 0),
```

Because I figured these statements were connected with 'OR' (according to the documentation) but even that only adds product types which have the attribute assigned...

Note that these values come from a drop down list, not sure if that matters though.

Comment: Where are you calling this from?  (what's the "$this" in the method call ->addCategoryFilter($this) )

Comment: I'm calling it in getProductCollection() in app/code/core/mage/catalog/model/category.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe it's too late, but this works for me:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
    ->addCategoryFilter($this)
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute' => 'color', 'null' => true),
            array('attribute' => 'color', 'in' => array(4, 6)),
        ),
        '',
        'left'
);
```

Comment: Only over a year too late but it does like what I needed, hopefully other people can still use it.

Comment: This code triggers a left join instead of inner, that's why it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand, give this a shot:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
    ->addCategoryFilter($this)
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'color', 'in' => array(4, 6)),'left')
);
```

Comment: I had to add an ) by the way, and depending on where I added it I got that error or simply not the desired result