# Finding all products with the same attribute on Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to do something that would seem simple but just doesn't work

I'm running Magento 1.5.1.

I would like to show on the product page all the items that have the same attribute set as the original item.
For example:

Item A has XYZ attributes, show me all the other items that have xyz attributes.

Nothing I've tried worked so far...

EDIT:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');      
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('orig_price');        

//filter for products who name is equal (eq) to Widget A, or equal (eq) to Widget B
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
        array('name'=>'orig_price','eq'=>'Widget A'),
        array('name'=>'orig_price','eq'=>'Widget B'),           
));

foreach ($collection as $product) {
        //var_dump($product);
        var_dump($product->getData());
}
```

EDIT 2:
I tried :

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection(); $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('color');

//filter for products who name is equal (eq) to Widget A, or equal (eq) to Widget B 
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(array( array('name'=>'color','eq'=>'red')
));

foreach ($collection as $product) { //var_dump($product); 
var_dump($product->getData()); }
```

and nothing at all showed up

Comment: I'd say it would a simple addAttributeToFilter to apply to the catalog/product collection. You should show us what you've try so far

Comment: you should put the code in your original question, so you can format it: right now, it's quite unreadable. On first sight, try addAttributeToFilter instead of addFieldToFilter, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403850/magento-addattributetofilter-but-ignore-for-products-that-dont-have-this-attrib

Answer (score 0):

First you should check that the attribute value for 'Used in Product Listing' is set to yes and than try the code below. I feel it will help you.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('color', 'red');
foreach ($collection as $product) { //var_dump($product); 
var_dump($product->getData()); }
```

once you get the filtered data than add other select & filter attribute as per your requirement.